# Cross arch remote debugging with gdbserver

Tags: gdb, mips, cross-compiling, gdbserver

I am trying to remotely debug a Hello World program that was cross-compiled
for mipsel but I am being unsuccessful in using gdb/gdbserver.

My target architecture is:

```
Linux debian-mipsel 2.6.32-5-4kc-malta #1 Tue Sep 24 01:20:35 UTC 2013 mips GNU/Linux
```

This system is running with QEMU and it can successfully execute the cross-compiled
file. (eg. ./bin/hello)

Currently, gdb version is 8.1.1 and gdbserver is 7.8, but I tried to change
both a lot and still getting the same result.

**Notes**

- The process is created and gdb starts listening.
- I can verify port is open with nc.

**gdbserver output**

```
new_argv[0] = "/bin/hello"
Process /bin/hello created; pid = 1385
>>>> entering linux_wait_1
linux_wait_1: [Process 1385]
my_waitpid (-1, 0x40000001)
my_waitpid (-1, 0x1): status(57f), 1385
LWFE: waitpid(-1, ...) returned 1385, ERRNO-OK
LLW: waitpid 1385 received Trace/breakpoint trap (stopped)
linux_low_filter_event: pc is 0x400190
pc is 0x400190
stop pc is 0x400190
my_waitpid (1386, 0x0)
my_waitpid (1386, 0x0): status(177f), 1386
my_waitpid (1386, 0x0)
```

**gdb output**

```
(gdb) file hello
Reading symbols from hello...done.
(gdb) target remote 10.0.0.2:12345
Remote debugging using 10.0.0.2:12345
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "timeout" in "qSupported" response
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote replied unexpectedly to 'vMustReplyEmpty': timeout
```

Comment: Ever figure this out? I'm having the same problem.